# Autodiscover failing

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, outlook-2007, autodiscovery

I'm having some problems with Autodiscover.  I have the SCP, I have the correct cert and it's still not working.  I'm out of ideas, anyone got one?

Result of "Test E-mail AutoConfiguration" in Outlook 07
[image]

Result of Get-ExchangeCertificate |fl
[image]

Result of Get-ClientAccessServer |fl
[image]

Comment: You need to get yourself over to https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ and see what it tells you. Very useful.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 - I was about to mention that myself. Great site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created a DNS A record for **autodiscover** which points to your CAS Server/CAS Array (and waited an appropriate time for propogation)?

Also, as mentioned - head over to www.testexchangeconnectivity.com which is an invaluable tool.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the correct url setup within Exchange/IIS. If you haven't already, you should check to make sure you have the correct DNS entries at your domain host. Check this page out, but here is a quick snippet of what you are likely missing outside of your environment.

http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/04/30/438249.aspx

> For non domain joined clients or clients that are not able to directly access the domain, Outlook is hard coded to find the Autodiscover end point by looking up either https://company.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml or https://Autodiscover.company.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml (where company.com is the portion of the users SMTP address following the @ sign). This means that to service clients in this scenario we must provide connectivity to one of these URLs. On the surface this should not be hard; but this connection is made over SSL and requires a valid certificate.

If Outlook cannot connect to either of those, Autodiscover will fail.